# Overload 1 of 2 on CASL can method

Tags: typescript, nestjs, casl

Hi I'm creating CASL auth in my nest app. Unfortunately i have this error on **Action.Update**

```
can(Action.Update, selectTeamSchema, { createdById: user.id });
```

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(action: never[], subject: never[], fields?: string | string[], conditions?: MongoQuery<never>): RuleBuilder<MongoAbility<PossibleAbilities, Conditions>>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'import("/src/ability/ability.factory").Action' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never[]'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(action: never[], subject: never[], conditions?: MongoQuery<never>): RuleBuilder<MongoAbility<PossibleAbilities, Conditions>>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'import("src/ability/ability.factory").Action' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never[]'.ts(2769)
(enum member) Action.Update = "update"
```

This is the code

```
type Subjects = InferSubjects<SelectUserType | SelectTeamType>;
type PossibleAbilities = [Action, Subjects];
export type Conditions = MongoQuery;

export type AppAbility = MongoAbility<PossibleAbilities, Conditions>;

export enum Action {
    Manage = 'manage',
    Create = 'create',
    Read = 'read',
    Update = 'update',
    Delete = 'delete',
}

@Injectable()
export class AbilityFactory {
    userInTeamAbility(user: SelectUserType) {
        const { can, cannot, build } = new AbilityBuilder(
            createMongoAbility<PossibleAbilities, Conditions>,
        );

        can(Action.Update, selectTeamSchema, { createdById: user.id });

        return build({
            detectSubjectType: (item) =>
                item.constructor as ExtractSubjectType<Subjects>,
        });
    }
}
```

The selectTeamSchema or SelectUserType are just zod objects. Any one know why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this:

```
new AbilityBuilder<AppAbility>(createMongoAbility)
```